# How to encode FLAC and DTS audio formats to AAC most efficiently?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, aac

I have been encoding audio for my own personal media library from various formats into AAC available for direct play on my Plex Server. I have been using the following command with `ffmpeg`:

`ffmpeg -i "input.format" -c:a aac -b:a 512k -ac 6 output.format`

The output audio however seems to be variable, of lesser quality and nowhere close to being 512kbps as attempted in the conversion parameters despite the input being, as an example, DTS. How would I go about converting my audio input files most efficiently to AAC? I have thought about uploading the audio tracks as private videos to YouTube and download their encoded AAC formats with the presumption of their encoding capabilities being superior to mine or the standard `ffmpeg` encoder.

Comment: 512 kbps strikes me as an odd choice for 6 channels. Maybe check again whether this is an appropriate choice.

Comment: @DanielB That's it - I ain't an expert on encoding and just want the best encoding quality possible

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg's AAC codec is nowhere near perfect – for better audio quality at the same bitrate, you should use `libfdk-aac` from Fraunhofer.

*Culprit: more likely than not, libfdk-aac support in FFmpeg is not supplied with your distribution for copyright and patent reasons. You may have to download libfdk-aac from your package manager, then build a separate FFmpeg from source with the usual configure-make-install sequence. The recommended way to download the source code is through `apt-get source` in Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives, and through `dnf download --source` in Fedora, CentOS and derivatives.*

Comment: Can I download it for Windows through `winget` perhaps? And what would be the command line option to achieve the best encoding?

Comment: Oh wait, I've been assuming Linux in the answer all the time, but in this case `winget` still won't help as the default LGPL builds don't come with `libfdk-aac` either even though the license is compatible. The command line options are to replace `-c:a aac` with `-c:a libfdk-aac` and to replace `ffmpeg` with your own FFmpeg with FDK.

Comment: What if I simply uploaded the audio to YouTube? Wouldn't they effectively do the encoding for me? Then I could simply pull the AAC track assuming their encoder is superior - also leaves me without the need or hassle of having to install FFmpeg with FDK (as I do not know how to do so)